# Converting between RFID output types?

Tags: arduino, number-formatting, uniqueidentifier, rfid, serial-number

I have an RFID reader hooked up to a Arduino and one that goes to a PC. The PC one has options to output in different formats. I have this code for my Arduino:

```
// interrupt that happens when INTO goes low (0 bit)
void ISR_INT0() {
  //Serial.print("0");   // uncomment this line to display raw binary
  bitCount++;
  flagDone = 0;
  weigand_counter = WEIGAND_WAIT_TIME;  

}

// interrupt that happens when INT1 goes low (1 bit)
void ISR_INT1() {
  //Serial.print("1");   // uncomment this line to display raw binary
  databits[bitCount] = 1;
  bitCount++;
  flagDone = 0;
  weigand_counter = WEIGAND_WAIT_TIME;  
}

if (bitCount == 26) {
    for (i=1; i<25; i++) {
        cardCode <<=1;
        cardCode |= databits[i];
    }

    printBits();
}
```

So this reads in binary and converts it to base 10

According to the PC reader, this is "8 no. in D(last 3bytes)", I want to convert my numbers to "10 no. in D(four byte)”, is this possible? Some examples:

```
Binary: 001001011010111111101011
Actual reading: 2469867
Wanted Reading: 0270905323
```

```
Binary: 001001011010000101101010
Actual reading: 2466154
Wanted reading: 0270901610
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to infer missing information out of nowhere. Since that reader only provides you parts of the information (i.e. 24 bits of 32 overall bits), there's simply no way to get the missing 8 bits (that the reader threw away between reading the tag and outputting the Wiegand frame).